# Kids' slang questions

Tags: slang

I'm ESL and have some questions on some of the phrases used in 'Dive Olly Dive!' "Hide and Seaweed" episode. Hope you can help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yst45J7SFCI

1. "...it's back to SURF with you" at the very beginning (at 0:46).
   Is it intended like "it's (time to go) back to SCHOOL with you"? (SURF is Olly's research/training facility) But if this is the
   case, isn't it more common to say "it's back to school
   FOR you," No? OR am I interpreting this wrong?
2. Into about 2:20, Olly says "Fishticks!" according to the script.
   I am guessing this is one of those malapropisms to avoid swearing for kids. But what is fishtick and what does "Fishticks!" mean? If it's "fish sticks!" I heard some kids saying in the sense of Gosh, Darn it, etc.
3. This may be a bit off the topic, but the big octopus character is said to be "GLAKEN" in this animation. His name is "GLAKEN" and Olly even says "Sea monster? (epiphany) You're **the GLAKEN**!" But I thought the monster is Kraken in Norwegian, Swedish, and also in English. What's the writer's intention for chosing to use GLAKEN instead of Kraken do you think?

Comment: Fishsticks I have heard of.  Note the extra *s* in there.

Comment: "Fish sticks" I suspect, is an aquatic play on words to replace the equally inoffensive [fiddlesticks](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fiddlesticks)

Comment: Rizzy, remember it's not real, fish don't actually talk, so it's permissible for the writers to *invent* words for their fishy kids world. If you listen carefully you can hear it's "fish-sticks" but that's an invented expression, same as "back to surf". And yes, your question about "Glaken" is off-topic (and probably unanswerable).

Comment: @Chappo - fish sticks are only “made up” in the sense that they are removed from the freezer and heated before being served for dinner.

Comment: “Glaken” sounds like a pun that Olly very proudly thought of, but I don’t know the show well enough to “get it”

Comment: @Jim oh, I never knew that! We (Aust, Brit) call those things *fish fingers*. So: not invented, but nonetheless an idiosyncratic usage. Or could this be a common U.S. *exclamation* I'm unfamiliar with? ;-)

Comment: Maybe not common, but easily grasped as “fishy pun” minced oath.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the comments. They are all very informative and helpful.

Comment: @Laconic Droid - replacing the fiddlesticks makes a lot of sense to me. I did not really think of that until you mentioned.

Comment: @Chappo - You are right about many expressions used in this sort of cartoons or animations are invented idiosyncratic words. Kids love odd things, rhythms, and uniquely made up words. That's why I would like to try to understand how they are funny or how these make sense to viewers. Although they are sometimes very difficult to grasp its meaning and humor particularly when combined with slang. Ugh.

Comment: @Jim - Fishy pun, yes exactly! They are using it throughout the cartoon which I am often having difficult time to "get" it. And thank you for your input on GLAKEN. I was trying to figure out if there was some intended humor or hidden meaning behind this particular word choice. Maybe Olly came up with this like you said. But I don't get this either, so maybe I should watch other episodes which may help to "get" this...

Comment: After watching that bit, I don’t think he’s making a pun when he says “Glaken” I think he’s in earnest about it being the sea monster of old- which we all know is the “kraken” but it sounds like Olly says “Klaken” to me.  I can’t get an ’r’ out if it any way I try.  And it’s not said in an accent that swaps “L” and “R”.  So I’m stumped.

Comment: @Jim - Thank you for watching the footage. Actually, I have their original script and there it is written "Glaken". That's why I was confused. Why the writer chose "Glaken" instead of Kraken. I wonder.

Comment: @GEdgar - Thank you for your comment. I've deleted my original commentas I read  your comment wrong. Glad to know that you too heard of "fishsticks" (well my case was "fish sticks" but that's the idea. Many kids in the US like fish sticks in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

1. *"Back to school **with** you"* is an acceptable variant of:

   **off with you!** in American English
   *go away! depart!*

   - [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-with-you)
2. *"Fishsticks"* is an invented exclamation suitable in a fantasy featuring  chatty denizens of the deep.  For a 1954
   example, consider [Bill Everett's *Sub-Mariner*](https://thehorrorsofitall.blogspot.com/2008/05/vengeance.html), with fishy
   exclamations like:

   > Sufferin' Shad!  What a way to die!

   *"Fishsticks"* is not a [malapropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism), and is not meant as oblivious unintentional humor.
3. Reasons for an author preferring ***Gl**aken* to ***Kr**aken* might
   include a penchant for sillier sounding less threatening names, and
   avoiding any possibility of litigation from from some jealous [rival
   production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraken_in_popular_culture#Film).